# Get line of string from ul li using javascript for each hierarchy level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I need to have a list of strings from the `ul` `li` with slash(/) separated till nth level of ul li using Javascript.

I tried with Jquery.map and each function but did not find any luck.

```html
<ul id="1">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    <ul id="2">
        <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a>
        <ul id="3">
            <li><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Required Result:**

```
First
Second/Second - 1
Second/Second - 2
Second/Second - 3/Aaa
Second/Second - 3/Bbb
Second/Second - 3/Ccc
Third
```

Comment: I believe you need a recursive function to handle this

Comment: Yes, you are right but how should be the recursion look like in my case. I tried as per my JS capability but did not find luck.

Comment: `Second/Second - 1/Aaa` should be `Second/Second - 3/Aaa`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter noted, recursion is the trick. As your looping your `<ul>`, you'll want to check each `<li>` for the existence of a nested `<ul>`. If so, you will call the function again, passing with it the nested `<ul>`, as well as the "prefix" of the string.

## Edit:

Based on your comments, the Default Parameter (and probably the rest (`...`) operator) will cause issues with your browser.

Forked JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h56zeqkg/

Here's a version with some legacy, IE11 friendly JS:

```
function stringBuilder(ul, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || '';
    var arr = [].slice.call(ul.children);
    var stringArr = arr.map(function (li) {
        if (li.children.length > 1) {
            return stringBuilder(li.querySelector('ul'), prefix + li.querySelector('a').textContent + '/');
        } else {
            return prefix + li.querySelector('a').textContent;
        }
    });
    return [].concat.apply([], stringArr);
}

stringBuilder(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

## Original:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hvojpds6/

Here's the snippet of JS:

```
function stringBuilder(ul, prefix = '') {
    return [].concat(...Array.from(ul.children).map(li => {
        // recurse
        if (li.children.length > 1) {
            return stringBuilder(li.querySelector('ul'), prefix + li.querySelector('a').textContent + '/');
        } else {
            return prefix + li.querySelector('a').textContent;
        }
    }))
}

stringBuilder(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

The output of `stringBuilder` will be an `array`, with the following:

```
stringBuilder(document.querySelector('ul'))
    (7) ["First", "Second/Second - 1", "Second/Second - 2", "Second/Second - 3/Aaa", "Second/Second - 3/Bbb", "Second/Second - 3/Ccc", "Third"]
    0: "First"
    1: "Second/Second - 1"
    2: "Second/Second - 2"
    3: "Second/Second - 3/Aaa"
    4: "Second/Second - 3/Bbb"
    5: "Second/Second - 3/Ccc"
    6: "Third"
    length: 7
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: There is error coming in console on the first line of function `SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'`

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig - Which browser? First line would probably indicate a support issue with the default parameter, `prefix = ''`. If that's the case, the other answer will probably work better for you :)

Comment: i am using IE11 edge

Comment: Gotcha! Let me add an answer that would work with IE11

Comment: Thanks, now it's working for me and am getting desire output.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse through your DOM with a recursive function

```js
//Main recursion
function getChildPaths($elements, parentPath) {

    //Traverse the children of each level
    $elements.children().each(function(){
    
    
      if ($(this).prop('tagName') === 'LI'){       

        //Check if this level has children
        if ($(this).children('UL').length > 0) {

          getChildPaths($(this).children('UL'), `${parentPath}/${$(this).children('A').html()}`) 
          
        }
        else {
          //Show the path if no children
          console.log(`${parentPath}/${$(this).children('A').html()}`)
        }
      }
        
    })   
}


getChildPaths($('#1'), '');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 200% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="1">
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    <ul id="2">
        <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a>
        <ul id="3">
            <li><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recurrsive function using `children()` and `each()` methods

```js
function getHierarchy($ul, level = '') {

  $ul.children('li').each(function(i, li) {
    let text = $(li).children('a').text();
    let list = $(li).children('ul');
    (list.length) 
      ? getHierarchy(list, level + text + '/')
      : console.log(level + text)
  });
  
}

getHierarchy($('#1'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="1">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    <ul id="2">
      <li><a href="#">Second - 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second - 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second - 3</a>
        <ul id="3">
          <li><a href="#">Aaa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bbb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ccc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am using IE 11

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig Are u using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursive_loop(parent, text) {
    if (text) {
        var c = parent.children;
        for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            var t = c[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent;                
            if (c[i].getElementsByTagName('ul').length) {
                return recursive_loop(c[i].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], text + '/' + t);
            }else{
                console.log(text + '/' + t);
            }
        }
    }
}
var parent = document.getElementById('1');
var c = parent.children;
for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var text = c[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent;        
    if (c[i].getElementsByTagName('ul').length) {
        recursive_loop(c[i].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], text);
    }else{
       console.log(text); 
    }
}    
recursive_loop(parent);
```